# detect insertion of portable device in windows

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, device-detection, removable-storage

i'm using a piece of c# code that detects connected devices and list them. the code is supposed to run on a kisok computer and help customers easily access and upload their files. the below code works fine except it does not recognize portable devices such as mobile devices.

```
public void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    int devType;
    char c;

    if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        // WM_DEVICECHANGE can have several meanings depending on the WParam value...
        switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            // New device has just arrived
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:

                devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);
                if (devType == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                {
                    DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol;
                    vol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)
                        Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                    // Get the drive letter 
                    c = DriveMaskToLetter(vol.dbcv_unitmask);

                    /* rest of handler is here */
                }
                break;

            case DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED:

                devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4); // m.LParam in this case is 0

                // handle portable device
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

so the mWParam received when connecting a mobile device is equal to DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED (0x0007) and the mLParam is 0. is it possible from this event to recognize a portable device? is there a related detection API i can add here?

I've tried the following WMI code but like before HandleEvent is only fired when usb is connected but not a mobile phone :(

```
    ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
    watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);
    watcher.Query = query;
    watcher.Start();
    watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp I used both and it works. I would recommend the second solution.

Comment: you used both with portable devices? i couldn't make the WndProc solution to work with mobile phones, as i stated above.

Comment: Im sorry. I interpreted "mobile" devices as "movable" devices . I havnt tested it with phones, i used USBs (as a dongle).

Comment: well for removable devices and hdd's the [Dolinay](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program) solution works great. thanks for the try :)