# How do I detect insertion of USB devices category wise in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, callback, usb, managementeventwatcher

```
USB thumb drives
USB harddisks
USB DVD writer
USB Bluetooth devices
USB headsets
usb mouse
USB keyboard
USB webcams / cameras
```

Just want to detect any sort of usb device using event handler...
Would appreciate any help...

```
WqlEventQuery q_creation = new WqlEventQuery();
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            q_creation.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
            q_creation.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);    //How often do you want to check it? 2Sec.
            q_creation.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'";
            var mwe_creation = new ManagementEventWatcher(q_creation);
            mwe_creation.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(USBEventArrived_Creation);
            mwe_creation.Start(); // Start listen for events
}                                                                                    
 /// <summary>
        /// Callback event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        internal void USBEventArrived_Creation(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Device Connected");
        }
```

This is the code what i had tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting USB drive insertion and removal using windows service and c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp)

Comment: this only detect the pen drive . not detect mouse and other devices

Comment: But it is a good starting point for your problem, isn't it? It means you need to spend some time on googling WMI, using which you can access anything. Show us that you've tried something and are not too lazy to search for answers

Comment: actually i had searched it in google also tried, my code is also detecting pendrive only.

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events) will  help.it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I am pasting my entire class for you, use as is (hookup the events right at the bottom for detecting or removal of USB) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlueMercs.Core.Services.WMI
{

  public class EventUsbMonitorEvent : EventArgs
  {
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Drive { get; set; }
  }

  public class UsbMonitor
  {
    private const string _queryForEvents = @"SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive'";
    private string _queryDiskPartitionDevice = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=\"{0}\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
    private string _queryDiskLogicalPartition = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"{0}\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";



    private readonly ManagementEventWatcher _watcher;
    private Thread _thread;

    public UsbMonitor()
    {
      _watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
      var query = new WqlEventQuery(_queryForEvents);
      _watcher.EventArrived += Watcher_EventArrived;
      _watcher.Query = query;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
      _watcher.Start();
      _thread = new Thread(Listen);
      _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
      try { _thread.Abort(); } catch { } //suppress thread abort exception
      _watcher.Stop();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
      _watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
      Listen();
    }

    private string GetDriveLetterFromDisk(string name)
    {
      name = name.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
      var driveLetter = string.Empty;
      var qryPartition = new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=\"" + name + "\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"); //string.Format(_queryDiskPartitionDevice, name));
      var partition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(qryPartition);

      foreach (var result in partition.Get())
      {
        //var qryLogicalDisk = new ObjectQuery(string.Format(_queryDiskLogicalPartition, result["DeviceID"]));
        var logicalDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"" + result["DeviceID"] + "\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"); //qryLogicalDisk);
        driveLetter = logicalDisk.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Aggregate(driveLetter, (current, x) => current + (x["Name"] + ","));
      }

      return driveLetter.Trim(',');
    }

    private void Watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
      ManagementBaseObject targetInstance;

      switch (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName)
      {
        case "__InstanceCreationEvent":
          targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
          if (targetInstance["InterfaceType"].ToString() == "USB")
          {
            var driveName = targetInstance["Caption"].ToString();
            var driveLetter = GetDriveLetterFromDisk(targetInstance["Name"].ToString());
            if (OnExternalUsbDetected != null)
              OnExternalUsbDetected(this, new EventUsbMonitorEvent { Model = driveName, Drive = driveLetter });
          }
          break;

        case "__InstanceDeletionEvent":
          targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
          if (targetInstance["InterfaceType"].ToString() == "USB")
          {
            var driveName = targetInstance["Caption"].ToString();
            var driveLetter = GetDriveLetterFromDisk(targetInstance["Name"].ToString());
            if (OnExternalUsbRemoved != null)
              OnExternalUsbRemoved(this, new EventUsbMonitorEvent { Model = driveName, Drive = driveLetter });
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventUsbMonitorEvent> OnExternalUsbDetected;
    public event EventHandler<EventUsbMonitorEvent> OnExternalUsbRemoved;
  }
}
```

Comment: this code is also detecting usb pen drive even not detecting mobile phone connected by data cable also other device not detected