# Cannot eject safely removed a USB memory stick when running a FileSystemWatcher on the drive

Tags: c#, wmi, filesystemwatcher, managementeventwatcher

I need to create a record file activity on my USB drive.

What I can do so far:

1. It detects the insertion and extraction (detects the extraction after the memory was removed) of a USB memory using ManagementEventWatcher:

   ```
   using System.Management;

   var insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
   var insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
   insertWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceInsertedEvent;
   insertWatcher.Start();
   ```
2. Using `FileSystemWatcher` I can record all the action, ex. Files created, modified, deleted and renamed:

   ```
        FileSystemWatcher m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        m_Watcher.Path = e.PathDevice + "\\";
        string strFilter = "*.*";
        m_Watcher.Filter = strFilter;
        m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = 
                     NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                     NotifyFilters.FileName;
        m_Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   ```

The problem:

As FileSystemWatcher is looking at the unit, if I try to eject the unit safely it tells me that I can not because the process of my application is using it. This variable when set to true `EnableRaisingEvents = true;` enable the events to listen to the changes in the memory and is the one that does not allow me to remove the memory safely, I did a test and start the application and I set it to false `EnableRaisingEvents = false;` and I can remove the memory safely.

Possible solution:

How can I detect the removal of the device before the operating system removes it? This way I can stop using the FileSystemWatcher on the device and remove the usb device safely.

Comment: There exists a [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) win32 API which you can use to receive [WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx) messages where `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` stands for hardware removal query. You may also want to check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events) for some explanation and code samples.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Thanks for the help, review in detail the information that you suggested, also try the code example, but I did not work to receive the messages DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE, if it works well for the messages DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE.

According to the official documentation, the [DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx) messages: Any application can deny this request. Maybe there is some application that is denying this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After several days looking for an answer to the planted problem **I found the solution**.*

[This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32026/Capturing-Device-Events-in-a-C-Windows-Service) was very helpful to solve the problem [and this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363427(v=vs.85).aspx).

The solution changes if we are using a service or a [windows form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events). ***My answer is based on a service***.

Services have a control handler which receives all messages from Windows. These might include codes to stop or pause the service, or as in our case, device events.  We need to register our own service handler, so we could catch device events. This would disable all callbacks like OnStop except OnStart, which is called before we tell Windows to use our handler.

The Windows API function for this is [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058(v=vs.85).aspx), which accepts a service name and a callback function to call when a message is received. We will call it in the OnStart function in our service.

The service control handler's signature is like this:

> public delegate int ServiceControlHandlerEx(int control,int eventType,
>   IntPtr eventData, IntPtr context);

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase{

  private FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher;
  private IntPtr deviceNotifyHandle;
  private IntPtr deviceEventHandle;
  private IntPtr directoryHandle;
  private Win32.ServiceControlHandlerEx myCallback;

  public Service1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
     base.OnStart(args);
     //
     RegisterDeviceNotification();

    fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fileSystemWatcher.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Created);
    fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Deleted);
    fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Changed);
    fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Renamed);
  }

}
```

**Register for Device Notifications**

In the OnStart method, apart from registering for a control handler, we will register for device notifications by using the `Win32` API function [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx). We give it our service's handle, a pointer to a `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` struct (telling the function to register for a class of devices), and some flags, among which is the `DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE`, which specifies that the caller is a service and not a window, for example. It returns a handle, which we must preserve in order to unregister when we don't need device messages anymore (for example, we could do this in the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` event).

Using this function allows us to capture the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` event types. We get them through the eventType parameter of our Service Control Handler. There, we can handle the `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT` and do anything we like.

```
  public void RegisterDeviceNotification()
  {
      InitArrayDevNotifyHandle();

      myCallback = new Win32.ServiceControlHandlerEx(ControlHandler);
      Win32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(service.ServiceName, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

      if (service.GetServiceHandle() == IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        // TODO handle error
      }

      Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface = new Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
      int size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterface);
      deviceInterface.dbcc_size = size;
      deviceInterface.dbcc_devicetype = Win32.DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
      IntPtr buffer = default(IntPtr);
      buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
      Marshal.StructureToPtr(deviceInterface, buffer, true);
      deviceEventHandle = Win32.RegisterDeviceNotification(service.GetServiceHandle(), buffer, Win32.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE | Win32.DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);

      if (deviceEventHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        // TODO handle error
      }

  }
```

***DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE - The Solution***

Here is the main thing to answer the question
I needed notifies to application of a change to the hardware configuration of a device. Specifically a USB memory change before SO will remove the memory. Thanks to @ZdeněkJelínek I was able to find the event `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` that permission is requested to remove a device or piece of media. This event is being held just before a device is about to be removed.

The solution is to create a handle to the device itself, use it in a `DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE` structure, and register with it to our Service Control Handler. In order to accomplish all this, it takes a couple of things:

Find which drive letter the device. I was able using the `ManagementEventWatcher` class, which allowed me to subscribe to the device insertion event and it provides me with information about the inserted device.
All this was done with the in order to get a device handle using the `CreateFileHandle` function. Only after that are we able to get the `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` event, disable the `FileSystemWatcher`, and allow the USB to be freely removed.

```
private int ControlHandler(int control, int eventType, IntPtr eventData, IntPtr context)
{
      if (control == Win32.SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP || control == Win32.SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN)
      {
        UnregisterHandles();
        Win32.UnregisterDeviceNotification(deviceEventHandle);
        base.Stop();
      }
      else if (control == Win32.SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT)
      {
        string c;
        switch (eventType)
        {
          case Win32.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
           //This is an example ... I do not use the DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL event, but it can be used. Instead use the ManagementEventWatcher class to detect when a device arrives and driveLetter.
              RegisterForHandle(driveLetter);
              fileSystemWatcher.Path = driveLetter + ":\\";
              fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
             break;
          case Win32.DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE:

              Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HDR hdrR;
              Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE dbhdl;
              hdrR = (Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)
              Marshal.PtrToStructure(eventData, typeof(Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));

              if (hdrR.dbcc_devicetype == Win32.DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE)
              {
                dbhdl = (Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE)
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(eventData, typeof(Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE));

                UnregisterHandles();
                fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                fileSystemWatcher = null;
              }

              break;
         }
       }

         return 0;
        }


private void UnregisterHandles()
{
    if (directoryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Win32.CloseHandle(directoryHandle);
        directoryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    if (deviceNotifyHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Win32.UnregisterDeviceNotification(deviceNotifyHandle);
        deviceNotifyHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

private void RegisterForHandle(char c)
{
    Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE deviceHandle = new Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE();
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceHandle);
    deviceHandle.dbch_size = size;
    deviceHandle.dbch_devicetype = Win32.DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
    directoryHandle = CreateFileHandle(c + ":\\");
    deviceHandle.dbch_handle = directoryHandle;
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(deviceHandle, buffer, true);
    deviceNotifyHandle = Win32.RegisterDeviceNotification(this.ServiceHandle, buffer, Win32.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
    if (deviceNotifyHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // TODO handle error
    }
}

public static IntPtr CreateFileHandle(string driveLetter)
{
    // open the existing file for reading          
    IntPtr handle = Win32.CreateFile(
            driveLetter,
            Win32.GENERIC_READ,
            Win32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Win32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            0,
            Win32.OPEN_EXISTING,
            Win32.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | Win32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            0);

    if (handle == Win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        return handle;
    }
}



public class Win32
{
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE = 1;
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES = 4;

    public const int SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP = 1;
    public const int SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT = 11;
    public const int SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN = 5;

    public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    public const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    public const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    public const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
    public const uint FILE_SHARE_DELETE = 4;
    public const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128;
    public const uint FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000;
    public static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

    public const int DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 5;
    public const int DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE = 6;

    public const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    public const int DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = 0x8001;
    public const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;

    public const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x219;

    public delegate int ServiceControlHandlerEx(int control, int eventType, IntPtr eventData, IntPtr context);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(string lpServiceName, ServiceControlHandlerEx cbex, IntPtr context);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                string lpszVolumeName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                string lpszVolumePathNames,
            uint cchBuferLength,
            ref UInt32 lpcchReturnLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(string
        lpszVolumeMountPoint, [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
        uint cchBufferLength);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr IntPtr, IntPtr NotificationFilter, Int32 Flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
            string FileName,                    // file name
            uint DesiredAccess,                 // access mode
            uint ShareMode,                     // share mode
            uint SecurityAttributes,            // Security Attributes
            uint CreationDisposition,           // how to create
            uint FlagsAndAttributes,            // file attributes
            int hTemplateFile                   // handle to template file
            );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
    {
        public int dbcc_size;
        public int dbcc_devicetype;
        public int dbcc_reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte[] dbcc_classguid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
        public char[] dbcc_name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
    {
        public int dbcc_size;
        public int dbcc_devicetype;
        public int dbcc_reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE
    {
        public int dbch_size;
        public int dbch_devicetype;
        public int dbch_reserved;
        public IntPtr dbch_handle;
        public IntPtr dbch_hdevnotify;
        public Guid dbch_eventguid;
        public long dbch_nameoffset;
        public byte dbch_data;
        public byte dbch_data1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a version of this solution, like the last way to manage this problem, and after several days testing and adapt my solution, when everything seems work, the DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE was the unique event that was not been calling correcty.... I was investigating and I found en microsoft observations  "The system may broadcast a DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE message without sending corresponding DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE and DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING messages. " and the solution will not work...