# Unity: Detect change in default devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, microphone

I am using unity in windows application that uses camera and microphone.

How to detect if the default device changes? For example if I plug an external microphone it will be the default microphone in windows, in this case I want to call a function when a change is made.

Comment: You may need to detect when the [Microphone.devices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone-devices.html)  array changes in the Update (checking the length may be enough)

Comment: I don't want to check for it manually. I want to find an event that handle it.

Comment: Have you checked [Check for device change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events) or [Hardware-Change-Detection](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119168/Hardware-Change-Detection)? What have you tried so far?