# Discover a new camera was connected with EDSKD

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

There's an event for camera being disconnected, but is there a way to detect that a new camera was connected to the system?

Or repeatedly asking for camera list is my best bet?

Comment: Is there publicy available documentation on the ED SDK? A quick search points me to a [register and request access to the API](https://developers.canon-europe.com/developers/s/camera) in the Canon website. From their description of the Eos SDK, looks like you should check also the documentation of their CCAPI

Comment: Maybe answers to this question can help you [Check for device change (add/remove) events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events). With the answers to that question you can check when a camera was connected in an event instead of repeatedly checking. I have used this solution for detecting if a USB cam was connected/disconnected.

Comment: @bradbury9 you get the SDK and the documentation after registering in Canon dev program, but I didn't find what I was looking for in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Read the EDSDK documentation...

See `EdsSetCameraAddedHandler`

I can't give any examples as you have not provided any info about which language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp
It is pretty old and as far as i know the developer doesn't support this anymore.

But it still works great for the most usecases. There is an event that fires if a camera gets added:

```
APIHandler = new CanonAPI();
APIHandler.CameraAdded += APIHandler_CameraAdded;
```

In the APIHandler_CameraAdded event you can change the camera settings or do whatever you want.