# Which is the equivalent of My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames in .NET 5/6?

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, serial-port

I need to work with serial ports, I had no problem in .net framework, but now porting on .NET 5 or above (wpf project), My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames is no more accessible.
Here a simple sub that not work anymore.

```
Sub GetSerialPortNames()
        ' Show all available COM ports.
        For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
            ListBox1.Items.Add(sp)
        Next
    End Sub
```

I added of course the import and the nuget package System.IO.Ports, but still get the exception BC30456'Computer' is not a member of 'myapp.My'.
Any advice?

Comment: [Not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) in .NET5+.  Use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() instead.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425