# Vsiual Studio 2019, serial comunication error : The port COM3 does not exist

Tags: c#, serial-port

When running a project in Visual Studio 2019 that requires serial communication, I get the error: The COM3 port does not exist. How could I solve this?

CODE:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnOffButton.Text = "OFF";
        }

        private void Form1_close(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void OnOffButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ON=="A0" && aux==false)
            {
                ON = "A1";
                serialPort1.WriteLine(ON);
                OnOffButton.Text = "ON";
                OnOffButton.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                ON = "A0";
                serialPort1.WriteLine(ON);
                OnOffButton.Text = "OFF";
                OnOffButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

        }
```

Comment: ...so... do you actually have a port named `COM3` or don't you?

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);` <-- Calling this is unnecessary: WinForms will end your process when the last `Form` is closed.

Comment: You should not be performing actions that have external side-effects inside a constructor, especially not a UI-level constructor like your `Form1()` ctor: move your `serialPort1.Open()` call to your `Form1_Load` event-handler or the `override void OnLoad` method - and wrap it in a `try/catch(  )` and catch [only the specific exception-types listed in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Comment: Open Device Manager and see whether you have COM3. And where is `SerialPort` variable and port name assignment?

Comment: You need to run as Admin to add a plug and play Com device.  Device may be Com4 instead of Com3,

Comment: Use the PowerShell commands at the end of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425) to determine the correct port.