# Communication between WaveShare USB CAN An or USB CAN B with WFA (Windows Form application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hardware, can-bus

I want to connect waveshare USB CAN A or USB CAN B to my Windows form application. I have tried achieving the communication using System.IO.Ports and LibUsbDotNet.

**Code which I have used for System.IO.ports:**

```
public class CanChecker
{
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private bool isConnected;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
    private ManualResetEvent readCompleteEvent;

    public bool IsConnected => isConnected;

    public string PortName => serialPort.PortName;

    public CanChecker()
    {
        serialPort = new SerialPort();
        isConnected = false;
        readCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // Hook up the event handler for data received
        serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
    }

    // Auto-detect the port to which the device is connected
    public void AutoDetectPort()
    {
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        foreach (string portName in portNames)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.PortName = portName;
                serialPort.BaudRate = 500000;

                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.Close();
                isConnected = true;
                return;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // The port is inaccessible, move on to the next one
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while checking port {portName}: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        isConnected = false;
    }

    // Write 8 bytes of data to the device
    public void WriteData(byte[] data)
    {
        if (isConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while writing data: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                serialPort.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device not connected. Cannot write data.");
        }
    }

    // Read 8 bytes of data from the device
    public byte[] ReadData()
    {
        if (isConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();

                // Begin an asynchronous read
                readCompleteEvent.Reset();
                serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, null);

                // Wait for the asynchronous read to complete
                readCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while reading data: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                serialPort.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device not connected. Cannot read data.");
        }

        return buffer;
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
            // Process the received data here if needed

            // Set the event to signal that the read operation is complete
            readCompleteEvent.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in ReadCallback: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle data received event if needed
        // This method will be called when data is received on the serial port
    }
}
```

from this code I was able to detect the USB CAN A PortName and and the write function didn't gave any error but neither the indicator RXD in CAN blinked and also was not able to read the data.

**Code which I have used for LibUsbDotNet:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Info;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public class CANDeviceManager
    {
        private readonly UsbDeviceFinder _deviceFinder;
        private readonly int _baudRate;
        public CANDeviceManager(int vendorId, int productId,int baudRate)
        {
            _deviceFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(vendorId, productId);
            _baudRate = baudRate;
        }

        public UsbDevice OpenCANDevice()
        {
            UsbDevice device = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(_deviceFinder);
            //device.SetBitRate();
            if (device != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAN device is connected.");
                return device;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("CAN device is not connected.");
            return null;
        }

        public void WriteData(UsbDevice usbDevice, byte[] data)
        {
            if (usbDevice != null)
            {
                UsbEndpointWriter writer = usbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep01);
                writer.Write(data, 1000, out _);
                Console.WriteLine("Data written to the CAN device.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAN device is not connected. Cannot write data.");
            }
        }

        public byte[] ReadData(UsbDevice usbDevice, int bufferSize)
        {
            if (usbDevice != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    UsbEndpointReader reader = usbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[bufferSize];
                    ErrorCode errorCode = reader.Read(receivedData, 100000, out _);

                    if (errorCode == ErrorCode.None)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received data: {BitConverter.ToString(receivedData)}");
                        return receivedData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error reading data: {errorCode}");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception while reading data: {ex.Message}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAN device is not connected. Cannot read data.");
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

From above code the Indicator blinks when I write the data but the Hardware to which my can is connected is not able to read the data I'm sending this can be because of mismatch of BAUDRATE but I'm not able to set the BAUDRATE in the above code, also the read data is not working.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425