# Using C# read data over serial port- 8 weigh scale connected to one multiport controller

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, scale

Need your help and advise on this. I am new to C# and trying to read data over serial. We have 8 weigh scale and connected to 8 port multiport controller. Now I am testing with first 2 ports.
I can read output string sometimes "S 0.006kg\r\n". Sometimes only S or "" or "\n" like that. Need your valuable suggestion.

```cs
namespace SimpleSerialLogic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string Selected_Port_Baudrate;
        public bool test1;
        public int count, portno;
        public byte[] data;
        public string Rx1, Rx2, Rx3, Rx4, Rx5, Rx6, Rx7, Rx8;
        public string response1, response2;
        public SerialPort COMport;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test1 = true;
            portno = 1;
            PortScanLogic();
        }
        public async void PortScanLogic()
        {
            COMport = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            COMport.ReadTimeout = 500;
            COMport.WriteTimeout = 500;
            //await Task.Delay(100);

            try
            {
                COMport.Open();

            }

            catch //Any other ERROR
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Open Port First scan");
                //COMport.Close();
            }
            if (portno > 8)
            {
                portno = 0;
            }
            if (portno < 0)
            {
                portno = 0;
            }
            if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
            {
                if (portno == 1)
                {
                    textBox9.Text = portno.ToString();
                    COMport.Write(Convert.ToString('\u0014') + "1");
                    COMport.Write("SI" + Convert.ToString('\r') + Convert.ToString('\n'));
                    //await Task.Delay(200);
                    Port1ScanLogic();
                    //await Task.Delay(500);
                }
                if (portno == 2)
                {

                    textBox9.Text = portno.ToString();
                    COMport.Write(Convert.ToString('\u0014') + "2");
                    COMport.Write("SI" + Convert.ToString('\r') + Convert.ToString('\n'));
                    //await Task.Delay(200);
                    Port2ScanLogic();
                    //await Task.Delay(500);
                }
         
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                PortScanLogic();
            }
            else
            {
                //GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled = true; // Enable the Receive Groupbox
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to Open the Port ");
                //COMport.Close();
            }
        }
        public async void Port1ScanLogic()
        {
            //Rx1 = COMport.ReadExisting();
            //textBox1.Text = Rx1;
            var bytesToRead = COMport.BytesToRead;
            byte[] Data1 = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            int received = COMport.Read(Data1, 0, bytesToRead);
            // you can specify other encodings, or use default
            response1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Data1);
            //COMport.DiscardInBuffer();
            textBox1.Text = response1;
            COMport.Dispose();
            //COMport.Close();
            await Task.Delay(500);
            portno = 2;
            PortScanLogic();
        }
        public async void Port2ScanLogic()
        {
            //Rx2 = COMport.ReadExisting();
            //textBox2.Text = Rx2;
            var bytesToRead = COMport.BytesToRead;
            byte[] Data2 = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            int received = COMport.Read(Data2, 0, bytesToRead);
            response2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Data2);
            //COMport.DiscardInBuffer();
            textBox2.Text = response2;
            COMport.Dispose();
            //COMport.Close();
            await Task.Delay(500);
            portno = 1;
            PortScanLogic();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
       
        public void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            COMport.Close();
        }
    } 
}
```

I would like show in text box "0.003" like that.

Comment: Outside the masses of code duplication: do not expect to read a complete "message" with one `Read` call. Accumulate data until you can identify a message separator. Ideally, you'd have a protocol to implement.

Comment: Thanks. My string always start with S and end with \n. Could you please share some example code?

Comment: I don't have any example code. There are tons of it out there, though. Probably even here on SO. But if I were you I'd start with a simple Console-App that does nothing else than read and detect messages from your source. That way, you don't get distracted by other issues caused by winforms, for example. If that works, "transplant" the code into your GUI-App.

Comment: But in pseudo, you basically read into a buffer. After each read you inspect the buffer for a complete message of "S ... \r\n". Then you cut that message out and process it. Wipe the buffer from everything before the end of that message, continue reading ... in a first approach, I'd even do that syncronously. You can always get more complicated with async and stuff later on.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425

Comment: "*My string always start with S and end with **\n**.*" - Since your device is sending *lines* of ASCII text, then simplify your receiving code by reading a line rather than just bytes. Let the OS do some of the input lexical scan work for you. But for robust code, the received data still needs to be verified for the expected format.