# Unhandled errors in serial port at VB.NET. How to catch them?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, usb

I am writing some code in VB.NET with serial port. It is virtual USB CDC (serial port) device connected to the host. Serial device is threaded as it is asynchronous to main thread.
As it is USB device, there are more several possible errors available in "Serial device". At least the are error if USB buffer overrun (when USB device is stalled)  and error when USB device is disconnected.

If I disconnect USB cable when running I receive:
"System.IO.IOException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."
(SerialPort.cs)

If I stall and restart MCU core in USB device:
System.IO.IOException: 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.'
(InternalResources.cs)

These errors appears after the USB-COM adapter is properly identified as USB device, was properly open and some data received/send.

How to catch these error in VB?

Standard Try-Catch-EndTry do not work...

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: _If I disconnect USB cable when running  I receive: "System.IO.IOException_: The solution seems simiple - don't disconnect the USB cable. If you haven't already done so, start by reading all of the documentation for [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) as well as, the documentation for your device. You may see if [SerialPort.DtrEnable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) is supported.

Comment: See [SerialPinChange Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialpinchange?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) for more information. Then subscribe to [SerialPort.PinChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425

Comment: Even if you "*catch these error(s)*" you still need to be concerned about message integrity. Does each message include a checkword (e.g. CRC32) to validate the message?

Comment: Some explanation: we live in real world, where USB cables can be removed. And I don't want to my application to get killed. I want to add simple message "Dear user, it seams, that your USB cable is disconnected", or "Dear user, the attached smart device is dead during operation. Try reconnecting cables",
It is not the DTR or other fancy serial stuff. It is USB device error in system.

Comment: _It is not the DTR or other fancy serial stuff. It is USB device error in system_: It seems that you haven't tested incorporating the information in the URLs that I provided nor do you yet understand how to use USB along with the _fancy serial stuff_.

Comment: For user246821, thanks for links. I am reading it. But I don't think that "SerialPinChange Enum" is connected to the problem. It is CDC USB device, it may not have "these pins" at all.

Comment: Please add the manufacturer and model number of your device to the post, as well as, a URL to the documentation for the device.

Comment: In one of the URLs posted above, shows how to detect when a USB device is plugged in, as well as, how to detect when a USB device is unplugged. It may be sufficient that once it's detected that a USB device has been unplugged, to get the list of available devices again. If the desired device is no longer present, then _Dispose_ the connection.

Comment: The manufacturer of the device is STM32 and Me :)
And I found bug in CDC firmware - USB command packet length is 10 bytes, meanwhile STM32 HAL somehow determined that 8 bytes is enough. This means, that pin status was request was bad. Somehow windows blocked reading this after few attempts and that why those event were not reported. When I changed firmware- everything is working!